# props are not accessible in the function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Inside `user.js` file the props are coming as empty I am unable to access the `match` in props. I don't understand why `props` is coming as empty  object.

App.js file

```
import "./App.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import User from "./components/User";


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/user/john">User</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>} ></Route>
            <Route exact path="/user/:name" element={<User/>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

user.js file

```
import React from 'react'

function User({match}){
    return (
        <div>
            User - {match.params.name}
        </div>
    )
}

export default User
```

Inside `user.js` file the props are coming as empty I am unable to access the `match` object in `props`. I don't understand why `props` is coming as empty object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` component isn't passed any props:

```
element={<User/>} // <-- no props are passed to User
```

With the way routed components are rendered in react-router-dom v6.x now they no longer are passed props (*`history`, `location`, and `match`, or any others*) and these ***must*** now be accessed via their respective hooks.

- `history` object is now a `navigate` ***function*** and accessed via [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)
- `location` object accessed via [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation)
- `match` object accessed via [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch)

***However***, the route params accessed directly via the [useParms](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) hook!

For a give route:

```
<Route exact path="/user/:name" element={<User/>} />
```

`User` can use the `useParams` hook to access the `name` route path parameter:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function User() {
  const { name } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      User - {name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the hook [`useMatch` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch) to access the current match.